# Symfony add parameters to render() via service rather than in controller

Tags: php, symfony

I am actually struggling with how to ask my question, hopefully it is clear. What I am trying to do is send additional information to the view when a specific service is being used other wise let the view render as it is. So here I go.

In symfony generally speaking when you want to render a view this is how you do it

```
return $this->render(
    'ExampleBundle:View.html.twig',
    array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'example' => $example
    )
);
```

Is it possible to add additional parameters via **service** to this `render()` just before the view is actually rendered, for example in above code I want `'example' => $example` to come from service.

Now of course, I can always call a service inside a controller and the `$example` data will get assigned to the `example` parameter being sent to the view

```
$example = $this->get('calculations')->TotalTax();//call to a custom service i created
```

But what I am asking is, if in service I can control/overwrite the view or the parameters being sent to the view.

So if the service is being used minupalate the parameters being sent to the view or change the view all together other wise let the view render as it is.

Comment: It is not clear, to me, what you mean by "if in service".  What service?

Comment: This is what i mean by [service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html). i have a custom service which i created to perform some tax related calculations, so in a controller where i am calling the service i need to pass additional information to view, i can get the info from service and then pass it to controller just fine, but i am asking if the via service i can override the view that gets rendered as this will be ideal solution. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Nope.  I guess it is a language thing.  I really can't see how a tax service should know anything about views.

Answer (score 0):

If u want service to select view to render and data to it, u can make service return eg

```
return array(
    'view' => 'ExampleBundle:View.html.twig',
    'data' => array(
         'example' => $example,
    )
);
```

and in controler:

```
$toRender = $this->get('calculations')->TotalTax();
return $this->render(
    $toRender['view'],
    array_merge(
        $toRender['data'],
        array('form' => $form->createView(),)
    )
);
```

but i think it is not good solution.

Comment: Thank you but this is not what I am looking for :)